# R: binning problem in multiple of consistent width

Tags: r, cut, binning

I have been searching for R cutting or binning packages but I could not quite find what I really want.

I have a dataset of 1000 variables and for some columns they might have values ranging from 0.01 to 0.2 but for some other they might have range from 0 to 2000. Some, on the other hand, might contain negative numbers.

I would like to plot the histogram for each of the variables but with a more consistent binning label, i.e. I would like the bin width in multiple of either 1,2.5 or 5 (for decimal numbers maybe of 0.01,0.02 or 0.05) and I am flexible of the bin numbers to vary between 20-40 bins(they can be fixed if it's easier) and not so care about the amount of data in each bin.

The reason for this is because I might get some new data for the same variables and I would like to have consistent binning to their distribution and perhaps model results in the same bin. And there are simply too much variables and I could not do them manually.

Any thoughts on how to write a function for this to return the bins consistent with old and new data before I get the new data.